# Docker Container cannot ping outside but can ping other container

Tags: docker, gitlab

I am following the [Networking with standalone containers Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/) for Docker on a Raspbian Server.

```
docker version
```

> Client:                                    Version:      17.05.0-ce
> API version:  1.29                        Go version:   go1.7.5                     Git commit:   89658be                     Built:        Thu May  4 22:04:27 2017    OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

> Server:                                    Version:      17.05.0-ce
> API version:  1.29 (minimum version 1.12) Go version:   go1.7.5
> Git commit:   89658be                     Built:        Thu May  4
> 22:04:27 2017    OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
> Experimental: false

I have created two alpine images for tests as mentioned in the documentation

```
docker run -dit --name alpine1 alpine ash

docker run -dit --name alpine2 alpine ash
```

and checked my bridge setting using

```
docker network inspect bridge
```

which is similar to the documentation.
output shown below

```
[
  {
    "Name": "bridge",
    "Id": "4a8b8e01c93870d8f9e1d91374897ff64e7d4be966bfc2a573fe64350b45229c",
    "Created": "2017-12-25T12:32:05.914410555+01:00",
    "Scope": "local",
    "Driver": "bridge",
    "EnableIPv6": false,
    "IPAM": {
      "Driver": "default",
      "Options": null,
      "Config": [
        {
          "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
          "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
        }
      ]
    },
    "Internal": false,
    "Attachable": false,
    "Ingress": false,
    "Containers": {
      "10da11879850d33f7dc66655a2ffc44d4fe6e7b741093671a984dd7855e2ec41": {
        "Name": "alpine1",
        "EndpointID": "0c1d9991bf1850619490118ffe200f3b4b9b6d8acdb17a02607b698dd5127e5d",
        "MacAddress": "MAC",
        "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.5/16",
        "IPv6Address": ""
      },
      "9c422ea752c31c363c6932ddfdc375078ae5c87c592d6e3f370ed55d8c257c1b": {
        "Name": "mosquitto",
        "EndpointID": "8018f38af49072357cfe78733f8c2c4ea6e41e94a6fb403ef3ac61459966954b",
        "MacAddress": "MAC",
        "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.4/16",
        "IPv6Address": ""
      },
      "ab40a23ecb83025d9aa1efc30f7c226679c64f9d0d22a7328baa71f7e4e7f72f": {
        "Name": "alpine2",
        "EndpointID": "e913aeae35017a09f5cd7ed3c7195867be26b70740efbbf3c8b7b8a0e75390c2",
        "MacAddress": "MAC",
        "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.6/16",
        "IPv6Address": ""
      },
      "c9eb7ed1c27ebf0fa4ed2a572c3f01760d4a1fb07654b76e3956171b61c71729": {
        "Name": "registry",
        "EndpointID": "d4bacc614f9ebc34b7ab0611a43f3cbcc8f5243be6c0defd00f56ed5be16dbcb",
        "MacAddress": "MAC",
        "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.3/16",
        "IPv6Address": ""
      },
      "eb99a70343381a50fe0b3b2a7c202c3cfd02e6a43741ed736a60f77739953947": {
        "Name": "fuseki",
        "EndpointID": "e4fc6f5b9b1eacb6a439fc7e749c33838f5d0562c8b0b5a92c3673fdd830498d",
        "MacAddress": "MAC",
        "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.2/16",
        "IPv6Address": ""
      }
    },
    "Options": {
      "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
      "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
      "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "false",
      "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
      "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
      "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
    },
    "Labels": {}
  }
]
```

I attach to one of the alpine containers and ping a generic website like google and I do not get any Ping responses.

however if I ping the other alpine container's IP Address I do get pings.

Strange enough, if detach the containers and ping the website from the host (server) I do get pings from the *outside net*.

Can this be problem related to the firewall setting setup for the Raspbian Server?

#### Purpose

I actually wish to run the `gitlab-runner`
[in a container](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/docker.html) and during [registering it](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/register/index.html#docker) I cannot send a POST Request from the Container to a GitLab CE.

Comment: On my local docker 17.12.0-ce ping from a container with default bridge network working ok. Can you provide the output of 'docker network inspect bridge'?

Comment: @AbylaySabirgaliyev I have added the result

Comment: Can you check IP forwarding on your host? https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#enable-forwarding-from-docker-containers-to-the-outside-world

Comment: It has also been enabled for all the Containers. @AbylaySabirgaliyev

Comment: It's not exactly related to the containers. It's your host's network configuration. You do it on the host where docker is installed.

Comment: I understand. My Docker server is configured to forward all IPv4 data. So I do not see that as a case for problem.

Comment: Also there's no correct MAC in the network inspect output. '"MacAddress": "MAC"'. It must show container's mac.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166766/discussion-between-shan-desai-and-abylay-sabirgaliyev).